# swift - Updating several uiimageview

Tags: swift, multithreading, uiview

I have been working on this project which needs several uiimageviews which, they are in a uicollectionviewcell, to be updated based on the information on the database!
i have tried background threads but it didnt help!im wondering why the images wont update!
here is my code

```
func update_cells()
{
    if sqlite3_prepare(self.db, "SELECT * FROM `habit_days` WHERE `habit_id` = \(self.id!)", -1, &self.stmt, nil) == SQLITE_OK
    {
        while(sqlite3_step(self.stmt) == SQLITE_ROW)
        {
            if(String(cString: sqlite3_column_text(self.stmt, 3 )) == "checked")
            {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    let image = self.view.viewWithTag(self.day_id) as? UIImageView
                    image?.image = UIImage(named: "mark")
                    self.day_id = self.day_id + 1
                }
            }else{
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    let image = self.view.viewWithTag(self.day_id) as? UIImageView
                    image?.image = UIImage(named: "uncheck")
                    self.day_id = self.day_id + 1
                }
            }
            self.date = String(cString:sqlite3_column_text(self.stmt, 2))
            let frmt = DateFormatter()
            frmt.dateFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"
            self.lastdate = frmt.date(from: self.date!)
        }
        self.todayedate = Date()
    }
}
```

any help would be appriciated

///////////////////
UPDATE

So i have changed my code to this and now i have my code working but still 1 problem :| all the cells are changing except the first one!

```
//
//  Habit_Activity.swift
//  Habit
//
//  Created by shayan rahimian on 3/3/18.
//  Copyright © 2018 shayan rahimian. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import SQLite3

class Habit_check: UIViewController,UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource{
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return days
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var des: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var col: UICollectionView!
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.layer.borderWidth = 1.5
        cell.layer.borderColor = self.hexStringToUIColor(hex: "#a0a0a0").cgColor
        let image = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20))
        print(indexPath.row)
        image.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.contentView.addSubview(image)
        return cell
    }


    @IBAction func back(_ sender: Any) {
        let back = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "habits_list") as? Habits_list
        self.present(back!, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func check(_ sender: Any) {
        let frmt = DateFormatter()
        frmt.dateFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"
        let mystr = frmt.string(from: todayedate)
        print(mystr)
        if ( days_passed > 0){
            sqlite3_exec(db, "INSERT INTO `habit_days`(`id`,`habit_id`,`time`,`state`) VALUES(null,\(self.id!),'\(mystr)','checked')", nil, nil, nil)
            let image = self.view.viewWithTag(day_id) as? UIImageView
            image?.image = UIImage(named: "mark")
            days_passed = 0
            day_id = day_id + 1
        }
        else{
            self.view.makeToast("باید از اخرین تغیریرات شما ۲۴ ساعت گذشته باشد", duration: 2.0, point: CGPoint(x: 110.0, y: 110.0), title: "", image: nil, style: ToastStyle.init(), completion: nil)
        }
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var cell_view: UIView!
    @IBAction func del(_ sender: Any) {
        let frmt = DateFormatter()
        frmt.dateFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"
        let mystr = frmt.string(from: todayedate)
        if ( days_passed > 0){
            sqlite3_exec(db, "INSERT INTO `habit_days`(`id`,`habit_id`,`time`,`state`) VALUES(null,\(self.id!),'\(mystr)','unchecked')", nil, nil, nil)
            let image = self.view.viewWithTag(self.day_id) as? UIImageView
            image?.image = UIImage(named: "uncheck")
            days_passed = 0
            day_id = day_id + 1
        }
        else{
            self.view.makeToast("باید از اخرین تغیریرات شما ۲۴ ساعت گذشته باشد", duration: 2.0, point: CGPoint(x: 110.0, y: 110.0), title: "", image: nil, style: ToastStyle.init(), completion: nil)
        }
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var name_label: UILabel!
    var id : Int!
    var db: OpaquePointer?
    var stmt:OpaquePointer?
    var name: String!
    var days: Int!
    var day_id = 0
    var date: String!
    var lastdate: Date!
    var todayedate: Date!
    var days_passed = 999
    weak var delegate: Habits_list!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        cell_view.layer.borderWidth = 3
        cell_view.layer.borderColor = self.hexStringToUIColor(hex: "#a0a0a0").cgColor
        cell_view.layer.cornerRadius = 10

        col.layer.borderWidth = 3
        col.layer.borderColor = self.hexStringToUIColor(hex: "#a0a0a0").cgColor
        col.layer.cornerRadius = 10

        des.layer.borderWidth = 3
        des.layer.borderColor = self.hexStringToUIColor(hex: "#a0a0a0").cgColor
        des.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        get_info()
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            self.update_cells()
            if (self.lastdate != nil) {
                self.days_passed = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day], from: self.lastdate, to: self.todayedate).day!
            }
        }

    }
    func update_cells()
    {
        if sqlite3_prepare(self.db, "SELECT * FROM `habit_days` WHERE `habit_id` = \(self.id!)", -1, &self.stmt, nil) == SQLITE_OK
        {

            while(sqlite3_step(self.stmt) == SQLITE_ROW)
            {
                if(String(cString: sqlite3_column_text(self.stmt, 3 )) == "checked")
                {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        let image = self.view.viewWithTag(self.day_id) as? UIImageView
                        image?.image = UIImage(named: "mark")
                        self.day_id = self.day_id + 1
                    }
                }else{
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        let image = self.view.viewWithTag(self.day_id) as? UIImageView
                        image?.image = UIImage(named: "uncheck")
                        self.day_id = self.day_id + 1
                    }
                }
                self.date = String(cString:sqlite3_column_text(self.stmt, 2))
                let frmt = DateFormatter()
                frmt.dateFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"
                self.lastdate = frmt.date(from: self.date!)
            }
            self.todayedate = Date()
        }
    }
    func get_info()
    {
        let fileNameToDelete = "habits.sqlite"
        var filePath = ""
        // Fine documents directory on device
        let dirs : [String] = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory, FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.allDomainsMask, true)
        if dirs.count > 0
        {
            let dir = dirs[0] //documents directory
            filePath = dir.appendingFormat("/" + fileNameToDelete)
            print("Local path = \(filePath)")
        } else
        {
            print("Could not find local directory to store file")
            return
        }
        let fileURL = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
            .appendingPathComponent("user.sqlite")
        if sqlite3_open(fileURL.path, &db) == SQLITE_OK
        {
            if sqlite3_prepare(db, "SELECT * FROM `habits` WHERE `id` = \(self.id!)", -1, &stmt, nil) == SQLITE_OK
            {
                while(sqlite3_step(stmt) == SQLITE_ROW){
                    self.name = String(cString: sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 1))
                    name_label.text = self.name
                    self.days = Int(sqlite3_column_int(stmt, 2))
                }

            }
        }
        }

      }
```

cell with tag number 0 is not changing! but other ones are ok.

///////////////////////
UPDATE 3 (Some how solved)

i have updated my code as below, it is not what i wanted but it is a work around in some way

```
//
//  Habit_Activity.swift
//  Habit
//
//  Created by shayan rahimian on 3/3/18.
//  Copyright © 2018 shayan rahimian. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import SQLite3

class Habit_check: UIViewController,UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource{
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return days + 1
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var des: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var col: UICollectionView!
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1, y: 1)
        if indexPath.row != 0 {
            cell.layer.borderWidth = 1.5
            cell.layer.borderColor = self.hexStringToUIColor(hex: "#a0a0a0").cgColor
            let image = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20))
            image.tag = indexPath.row
            cell.contentView.addSubview(image)
        }
        return cell
    }


    @IBAction func back(_ sender: Any) {
        let back = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "habits_list") as? Habits_list
        self.present(back!, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func check(_ sender: Any) {
        let frmt = DateFormatter()
        frmt.dateFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"
        let mystr = frmt.string(from: todayedate)
        print(mystr)
        if (day_id <= days) {
            if ( days_passed > 0){
                sqlite3_exec(db, "INSERT INTO `habit_days`(`id`,`habit_id`,`time`,`state`) VALUES(null,\(self.id!),'\(mystr)','checked')", nil, nil, nil)
                let image = self.view.viewWithTag(day_id) as? UIImageView
                image?.image = UIImage(named: "mark")
                days_passed = 0
                day_id = day_id + 1
            }
            else{
                self.view.makeToast("باید از اخرین تغییرات شما ۲۴ ساعت گذشته باشد", duration: 2.0, point: CGPoint(x: 110.0, y: 110.0), title: "", image: nil, style: ToastStyle.init(), completion: nil)
            }
        }else{
            self.view.makeToast("تعداد روز های عادت شما به پایان رسیده", duration: 2.0, point: CGPoint(x: 110.0, y: 110.0), title: "", image: nil, style: ToastStyle.init(), completion: nil)
        }
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var cell_view: UIView!
    @IBAction func del(_ sender: Any) {
        let frmt = DateFormatter()
        frmt.dateFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"
        let mystr = frmt.string(from: todayedate)
        if (day_id <= days) {
            if ( days_passed > 0){
                sqlite3_exec(db, "INSERT INTO `habit_days`(`id`,`habit_id`,`time`,`state`) VALUES(null,\(self.id!),'\(mystr)','unchecked')", nil, nil, nil)
                let image = self.view.viewWithTag(self.day_id) as? UIImageView
                image?.image = UIImage(named: "uncheck")
                days_passed = 0
                day_id = day_id + 1
            }
            else{
                self.view.makeToast("باید از اخرین تغیریرات شما ۲۴ ساعت گذشته باشد", duration: 2.0, point: CGPoint(x: 110.0, y: 110.0), title: "", image: nil, style: ToastStyle.init(), completion: nil)
            }
        }else{
            self.view.makeToast("تعداد روز های عادت شما به پایان رسیده", duration: 2.0, point: CGPoint(x: 110.0, y: 110.0), title: "", image: nil, style: ToastStyle.init(), completion: nil)
        }
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var name_label: UILabel!
    var id : Int!
    var db: OpaquePointer?
    var stmt:OpaquePointer?
    var name: String!
    var days: Int!
    var day_id = 1
    var date: String!
    var lastdate: Date!
    var todayedate: Date!
    var days_passed = 999
    weak var delegate: Habits_list!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        get_info()
        des.textAlignment = .right
        des.makeTextWritingDirectionRightToLeft(self)
        col.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1, y: 1)
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        cell_view.layer.borderWidth = 3
        cell_view.layer.borderColor = self.hexStringToUIColor(hex: "#a0a0a0").cgColor
        cell_view.layer.cornerRadius = 10

        col.layer.borderWidth = 3
        col.layer.borderColor = self.hexStringToUIColor(hex: "#a0a0a0").cgColor
        col.layer.cornerRadius = 10

        des.layer.borderWidth = 3
        des.layer.borderColor = self.hexStringToUIColor(hex: "#a0a0a0").cgColor
        des.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            self.update_cells()
            if (self.lastdate != nil) {
                self.days_passed = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day], from: self.lastdate, to: self.todayedate).day!
            }
        }
    }
    func update_cells()
    {
        if sqlite3_prepare(self.db, "SELECT * FROM `habit_days` WHERE `habit_id` = \(self.id!)", -1, &self.stmt, nil) == SQLITE_OK
        {

            while(sqlite3_step(self.stmt) == SQLITE_ROW)
            {
                if(String(cString: sqlite3_column_text(self.stmt, 3 )) == "checked")
                {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        let image = self.view.viewWithTag(self.day_id) as? UIImageView
                        image?.image = UIImage(named: "mark")
                        self.day_id = self.day_id + 1
                    }
                }else{
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        let image = self.view.viewWithTag(self.day_id) as? UIImageView
                        image?.image = UIImage(named: "uncheck")
                        self.day_id = self.day_id + 1
                    }
                }
                self.date = String(cString:sqlite3_column_text(self.stmt, 2))
                let frmt = DateFormatter()
                frmt.dateFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"
                self.lastdate = frmt.date(from: self.date!)
            }
            self.todayedate = Date()
        }
    }
    func get_info()
    {
        let fileNameToDelete = "habits.sqlite"
        var filePath = ""
        // Fine documents directory on device
        let dirs : [String] = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory, FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.allDomainsMask, true)
        if dirs.count > 0
        {
            let dir = dirs[0] //documents directory
            filePath = dir.appendingFormat("/" + fileNameToDelete)
            print("Local path = \(filePath)")
        } else
        {
            print("Could not find local directory to store file")
            return
        }
        let fileURL = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
            .appendingPathComponent("user.sqlite")
        if sqlite3_open(fileURL.path, &db) == SQLITE_OK
        {
            if sqlite3_prepare(db, "SELECT * FROM `habits` WHERE `id` = \(self.id!)", -1, &stmt, nil) == SQLITE_OK
            {
                while(sqlite3_step(stmt) == SQLITE_ROW){
                    self.name = String(cString: sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 1))
                    name_label.text = self.name
                    self.des.text = String(cString: sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 3))
                    self.days = Int(sqlite3_column_int(stmt, 2))
                }

            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: `UICollectionViewCell` instances are enqueued/dequeued multiple times during the collection view lifecycle, it could be by the results the cells hold other contents.

Comment: So , @Cristik , do you know any work around?

Comment: Not sure, I can't tell from the code you posted how do you configure the cells, where how your `viewWithTag` works (where do views get the tag). Can you update the question with as much details/code as you can related to the problem. Though try not to go to the other extreme of posting too much code :)

Comment: @Cristik i have updated my question, can you help?

Comment: Have you tried debugging the code? Maybe add some logs around the `UIImage` code to see if the image gets sent to the proper view?

Comment: @Cristik i have updated my code, it is working now by my work around, still is not what i wanted.

Comment: I'd recommend to ask another question that summarize your efforts from this question. In it's current form the question is too broad and is hard to grasp by viewers. Asking a new and clear question will also help you get more views on it.